# Conditionally Serialize XML in C# Based on Attribute

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I have an XML file which I need to serialize into C# objects. Ordinarily, the XML tags dictate which object the file is serialized into. However, one of the files which I must handle uses an attribute in the XML tag called type to specify the object. For example, see the code below.

```
<library>
  <item type="book">Great Expectations</item>
  <item type="magazine">National Geographic</item>
  <item type="cd">Blue Valentines</item>
</library>
```

Is it possible to use XML serialization attributes such that each item will serialize into an object whose type is specified by the type attribute in the XML, i.e. Great Expectations will serialize into a book object, etc?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Does it make sense to use separate object bytes for book/magazine/cd here as opposed to just an Item object with a Type property? Does your actual document has more fields or something?

Comment: It's certainly possible to write an XML Serializer by hand that will read the attributes and perform the proper serialization. That's a lot of work, however; it might actually be easier to write an XSLT that transforms the XML into a form that wraps each item in its proper type (only being slightly tongue-in-cheek).

Answer (score 0):

Check out another StackOverflow question: [XML Deserialization - convert attribute value into class automatically (.net)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/421660/xml-deserialization-convert-attribute-value-into-class-automatically-net).

Deserializing an array item into a specific type doesn't appear to be supported by the attributes alone. You will need to implement a custom IXmlSerializable.